# Conditional formatting of `Table` with `Join` and `Transpose`

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation, conditional

A simple example of what I'm trying to do (but I want to be able to apply the same principle to much larger data sets and with more complicated functions for `low` and `high`):

```
data = {1, 5, 6, 9, 13, 20, 67, 68, 80, 97}; 
xList = Range[10]; 
low = (#1^1.9 & ) /@ xList; 
high = (#1^2.1 & ) /@ xList; 
table = Transpose[Join[{xList, low, data, high}, 2]]; 
TableForm[table]
```

I want to apply a conditional `Style` to `data`:

```
If[low < data < high, Style[data, Green], Style[data, Red]]
```

Easy in principle - but everything I have tried results in error messages and strings of data that aren't in `TableForm`.

How do I do it?

UPDATE:

Many thanks to @Lucas Lang for leading me to

```
data = {1, 5, 6, 9, 13, 20, 67, 68, 80, 97};
xList = Range[10];
low = (#1^1.9 &) /@ xList;
high = (#1^2.1 &) /@ xList;
TableForm@
 MapThread[{#, #2, Style[#3, If[Less@##2, Green, Red]], #4} &, {xList,
 low, data, high}]
```

This works - but only until I add an extra column. I'd like to add a column that gives `high-low`. But when I do so, all the green items in the column `data` go red...

```
data = {1, 5, 6, 9, 13, 20, 67, 68, 80, 97};
xList = Range[10];
low = (#1^1.9 &) /@ xList;
high = (#1^2.1 &) /@ xList;
highMinusLow = high - low;
TableForm@
 MapThread[{#, #2, 
  Style[#3, If[Less@##2, Green, Red]], #4, #5} &, {xList, low, data,
  high, highMinusLow}]
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Just a small remark: `Join[{xList, low, data, high}, 2]` doesn't actually join anything. It just returns the list `{xList, low, data, high}`. `Join` works by supplying lists as separate arguments, not by supplying them all in a list in the first argument. However, `Join[xList, low, data, high, 2]` will only work for matrices or higher order arrays (joining their columns together).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) to apply a function to each entry:

```
TableForm@MapThread[
  Style[#3, If[#2 < #3 < #4, Green, Red]] &,
  {xList, low, data, high}
  ]
```

[image]

Closer to your original code:

```
TableForm@MapThread[
  If[#2 < #3 < #4, Style[#3, Green], Style[#3, Red]] &,
  {xList, low, data, high}
  ]
(* same output *)
```

With the other columns present as well:

```
TableForm@MapThread[
  {#, #2, Style[#3, If[#2 < #3 < #4, Green, Red]], #4} &,
  {xList, low, data, high}
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Lucas Lang. I'm very grateful for this - but could you please see the update to the OP? If I add another column, it all goes wrong...

Comment: Ooops, I might have gone to far with the conciseness... it should work now - the issue was that `Less@##2` is equivalent to `#2<#3<#4<...` - which obviously breaks if you add more columns. Explicitly writing `#2<#3<#4` fixes the issue